# Will driving with damaged inner tie rod damage outer ends?

Tags: ford, suspension, focus, tie-rod

I have a 2002 Ford Focus and both the inner and outer tie rods need replacing. However, I'm on a short deadline because I'm moving at the end of the month and need to get this car working ASAP.

I already have the new outer tie rod ends on hand, but don't have the inner ones or the stupid custom tool Ford required to remove their stock tie rods, and I don't have time to wait for them to be shipped here.

So I wanted to just replace the outer tie rod ends for now, and do the inner ones later once we've settled into our new place. But I'm wondering if driving it around with the old busted inner tie rods is going to do damage to my new outer tie rod ends?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Driving around with the outer ones good while the inner ones are toast should not cause problems with good outer ones ...

### ... HOWEVER ...

Your real issue here is not whether damage will occur to your outer tie rods, but whether the car is safe to drive with ugly inner ones. You'll have to assess whether the health and well being of your family, yourself, and those around you is worth the risk of one of the inner tie rods letting loose. Is this a regular occurrence? Not really, but worn tie rod ends can cause any multitude of control issues with the car, some of which you may not be able to control. Again, this is something you'll need to decide for yourself.